# How to identify the source of JavaFX Property changes?

Tags: javafx

how can the source of a JavaFX property change be identified, i.e. *who* changed the property?

--

Example: the "selected" state of a CheckBox must be synchronized with another objects state, and the other object is not supporting Properties or Bindings. The obvious approach would be to register a `ChangeHandler` at the selectedProperty of the CheckBox in order to update the other objects state. In the opposite direction, another notification facility is used to call `setSelected()` or `selectedProperty.set()` of the CheckBox. This leads to a problem: the registered ChangeHandler is called not only when the user clicks the CheckBox in the UI, but also when the other object changes its state.

In the latter case, we dont want to propagate the change back to the object, of course. Surprisingly there does not seem to be anything on which the ChangeHandler could decide whether the Property was changed by the UI control itself or from outside. The first argument of the handler function only refers to the Property/Observabe *which* is changed, not *who* changed it. The `oldValue` and `newValue` arguments can be used to break an infinite notification cycle, but they are not sufficient to prevent the first unneccessary, possibly harmful notification.

--

The above description should be sufficient, but if you prefer this question in form of a minimal working example, the following code demonstrates the problem:

The "other object" with one boolean flag as "state" (a database in the real world):

```
package sample;

public class SomeDatabaseEntry {

    private boolean someFlag = false;

    public boolean getSomeFlag()
    {
        return someFlag;
    }

    public void setSomeFlag(boolean state)
    {
        someFlag = state;
    }

    public void toggleSomeFlag()
    {
        someFlag = !someFlag;
    }

}
```

Main:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    /*
     * dummy object representing the "other side", e.g. a database
     */
    public final SomeDatabaseEntry _someEntry = new SomeDatabaseEntry();

    private Controller _controller;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml").openStream());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

        _controller = fxmlLoader.getController();
        _controller.init(_someEntry);

        startSomeDummyDatabaseUpdater();
    }


    /*
     * dummy logic that emulates external changes (e.g. database updates)
     * in the real world there would be a function that is called by the
     * database with a description of the changes that occured.
     * as said: this part is not under my control
     */
    public void startSomeDummyDatabaseUpdater()
    {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true)
            {
                _someEntry.toggleSomeFlag();
                _controller.updateUIFromDatabase();

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The controller handling user input and the other objects state (database):

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;

public class Controller {

    private SomeDatabaseEntry _someEntry;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox myCheckBox;

    public void init(SomeDatabaseEntry entry)
    {
        _someEntry = entry;

        myCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                // If the user toggled the CheckBox in the UI, update the state of the database
                // PROBLEM: this handler is also called in the context of a database update (function below)
                //          in this case the database must not be updated (e. g. because the update is expensive)
                _someEntry.setSomeFlag(newValue);
                System.out.println("Database was updated: " + newValue);
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateUIFromDatabase()
    {
        myCheckBox.selectedProperty().setValue(_someEntry.getSomeFlag());
    }

}
```

FXML:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<GridPane fx:id="root" fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <CheckBox fx:id="myCheckBox" text="someFlag"></CheckBox>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Assuming the problem is about `ChangeListener`: there is no information about in the parameters or in the property itself. Of course you could create a stacktrace and inspect it but I strongly recommend not doing this. You probably should create method for setting the property and set a flag that indicates a change from code...

Comment: Bidirectional bindings in the properties API set a flag to prevent circular notifications; I think it sounds like you want to mimic the same thing. You can see the implementation [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/9/rt/file/c734b008e3e8/modules/javafx.base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/binding/BidirectionalBinding.java).

Comment: Yes, it would be possible to manually maintain a flag. Just had a quick look into the code you linked, @James_D. The boolean field "updating" declared on line 230 seems to be the thing. But I'm appalled by this solution, it is rather a hack. Something like this must be supported by the framework! Looks like it was a big mistake to use java beans for bindings... Do you know anything about thread safety of the solution in BidirectionalBinding?

Comment: JavaFX properties are, by design, single threaded. Not sure what you mean about "must be supported by the framework" - the code you're looking at is the actual implementation of the framework, so clearly it supports it. Not sure how else you would choose to implement this.

Comment: your setup is wrong if you need to differentiate between "user-triggered" and "other-triggered" on the level of the listener .. add some indirection to separate the execution paths. Anyway, best to show an example that demonstrates what you are after and how it doesn't work out, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: With "must be supported by the framework" I meant that the source of changes should be a part of the API, like it is the case for other UI events (mouse clicks etc.). This is a well-established solution for different kinds of synchronization problems. It also works irrespectively of the thread. It looks like JavaFX currently supports synchronization only internally, i.e. between JavaFX properties. This is a very specific situation. In the real world JavaFX must be connected with existing software that is not aware of JavaFX.

Comment: @kleopatra: I cannot change the setup. The only way to get notified about changes of the Checkbox is the ChangeHandler. And the only way to update the CheckBox is setting the Property. Please tell me, *where* could I separate the execution path?

Comment: you can always add a buffered property: in it you have full control ...

Comment: Don't know anything about buffered properties, will start a search, thanks. My current feeling is that I will introduce a "setFromOutside" flag, that is always raised when I update the property from outside and is cleared in the ChangeHandler. I will have to find out how the ChangeHandler is called (from the event queue or immediately) and potentially will need some guards. Thanks so far...

Comment: The source of the changes is part of the API; you can request which property fired the change, in exactly the same way that you can ask an event which object fired the event. You are asking for something more: you are asking for the object that called the method that caused the property to change. As others have pointed out, if you need this, your design is flawed. No method, anywhere, should ever care what caused it to be invoked.

Comment: @James_D I have to react on the CheckBox "selected" state. I can only do this in the ChangeHandler. I also have to change the "selected" state of the CheckBox, and this will always call my ChangeHandler. This is not my design. It is the design of JavaFX that forces me to "know the object that called the method". I agree that this isn't good, but it is not my fault.

Comment: But that's a perfectly sensible design. If that doesn't work for what you need, you must, in some sense, be trying to use the selected state of the check box to represent multiple things. Anyway, this is all moot. While you steadfastly refuse to provide enough information in your question, you're not going to have any chance of an answer.

Comment: I honestly don't know what to add to my question. I have to react on the user input (CheckBox selection state) to synchronize the represented value (true/false) with another object. This object is also updated, which is not under my control. I don't want to use the "selected state of the check box to represent multiple things", but due to the design of JavaFX we end up there. I don't blame you for that, I appreciate your help. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: See @kleopatra's first comment for how to improve the question. The main problem is you are asking about a proposed solution (which won't work, because the API doesn't - in fact probably can't - support it), but we don't have any real idea what the problem is. So create a simple example application that demonstrates the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @James_D: I have added a minimal working example to the question, please upvote my question if it helps. If you have any new ideas, please answer the question. If the framework really does not provide support to solve my problem I will accept this answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just introduce an additional property. Typically this would be part of the model.

```
public class UIModel {

    private final BooleanProperty value = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public BooleanProperty valueProperty() {
        return value ;
    }

    public final boolean getValue() {
        return valueProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setValue(boolean value) {
        valueProperty().set(value);
    }

    // other properties, etc...
}
```

Now you create an instance of your model and share that instance with interested parties, e.g. using dependency injection, etc.

Your controller should do something like

```
public class Controller {

    @Inject // or inject it by hand, just imagining DI here for simplicity
    private UIModel model ;

    @Inject
    private DAO dao ;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox myCheckBox ;

    public void initialize() {

        model.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            myCheckBox.setSelected(newValue));
        myCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
            if (model.getValue() != isNowSelected) {
                updateDatabase(isNowSelected);
                model.setValue(isNowSelected);
            }
        });

    }

    private void updateDatabase(boolean value) {
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                dao.update(value);
                return null ;
            }
        };
        task.setOnFailed(e -> { /* handle errors */ });
        new Thread(task).start() ; // IRL hand to executor, etc.
    }
}
```

Now your "updates from database" (which I assume represent changes that have already occurred to the external database) look like

```
UIModel model = ... ; // from DI or wherever.
while (! Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> model.setValue(! model.getValue()));
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

The point here is that you update the model, bringing it into sync with the external resource. The listener on the model updates the check box, so those are now consistent. That fires the listener on the check box's selected state, but that listener doesn't update the database if the model and check box are already in sync, which is the case if the check box was changed because of a change in the model.

On the other hand, if the user checks the check box, the model will not be in sync, so the listener updates the database and then brings the model in sync with the UI and database.

In any real application, it's going to be desirable to define a UI model (which may be more than one class) anyway, as you want to separate the UI state from the views and controllers. How you manage the exact interface of model to back-end services might vary somewhat, and you may need to modify where things sit in relation to that interface, but this separation should provide the means to do what you need, as in this example.

Comment: Thank you! My application already has its own UI model. It is what I called "database" in my MWE to comprise my question. Unfortunately, I cannot query the current value using `model.getValue() != isNowSelected` from the ChangeListener, since the model could have already been changed again at that point of time (concurrency). But your answer is perfectly fine. Introducing a second UI model is a valid approach to solve the situation. But it should still be stated clearly that it is merely a workaround for missing support of JavaFX to synchronize with the outside world.